# multiple async not working perfectly when using wifi but working on mobile network perfectly

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I have 3 async calls executed in OnCreate() I am executing all 3 which fetches data and updates the listview .This works perfectly on Mobile network but on Wifi it does not work sometime.Also,I am guessing its happening parallel .

Please let me know why it does not work perfectly on wifi.Also let me know if this is perfect to execute 3 async calls at a time.I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


         listview1 = new ListView(mContext);
         listview2 = new ListView(mContext);
         listview3 = new ListView(mContext);


         ////


            arraylist1 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            new LoadInbox1().execute();

                        arraylist2 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            new LoadInbox2().execute();


                        arraylist3 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            new LoadInbox3().execute();

    }





    class LoadInbox1 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Inbox ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting Inbox JSON
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(INBOX_URL, "GET",
                    params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Inbox JSON: ", json.toString());

            try {
                inbox = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MESSAGES);
                // looping through All messages
                for (int i = 0; i < inbox.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = inbox.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String from = c.getString(TAG_FROM);
                    String subject = c.getString(TAG_SUBJECT);
                    String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_FROM, from);
                    map.put(TAG_SUBJECT, subject);
                    map.put(TAG_DATE, date);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    arraylist1.add(map);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */

                     listview1.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(
                                MainActivity.this, arraylist1,
                                R.layout.inbox_list_item, new String[] { TAG_FROM, TAG_SUBJECT, TAG_DATE },
                                new int[] { R.id.from, R.id.subject, R.id.date }));


                }
            });

        }

    }






    class LoadInbox2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Inbox ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting Inbox JSON
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(INBOX_URL, "GET",
                    params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Inbox JSON: ", json.toString());

            try {
                inbox = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MESSAGES);
                // looping through All messages
                for (int i = 0; i < inbox.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = inbox.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String from = c.getString(TAG_FROM);
                    String subject = c.getString(TAG_SUBJECT);
                    String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_FROM, from);
                    map.put(TAG_SUBJECT, subject);
                    map.put(TAG_DATE, date);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    arraylist2.add(map);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */

                     listview2.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(
                                MainActivity.this, arraylist2,
                                R.layout.inbox_list_item, new String[] { TAG_FROM, TAG_SUBJECT, TAG_DATE },
                                new int[] { R.id.from, R.id.subject, R.id.date }));


                }
            });

        }

    }




    class LoadInbox3 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Inbox ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting Inbox JSON
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(INBOX_URL, "GET",
                    params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Inbox JSON: ", json.toString());

            try {
                inbox = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MESSAGES);
                // looping through All messages
                for (int i = 0; i < inbox.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = inbox.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String from = c.getString(TAG_FROM);
                    String subject = c.getString(TAG_SUBJECT);
                    String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_FROM, from);
                    map.put(TAG_SUBJECT, subject);
                    map.put(TAG_DATE, date);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    arraylist3.add(map);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */

                     listview3.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(
                                MainActivity.this, arraylist3,
                                R.layout.inbox_list_item, new String[] { TAG_FROM, TAG_SUBJECT, TAG_DATE },
                                new int[] { R.id.from, R.id.subject, R.id.date }));


                }
            });

        }

    }
```

logcat

```
02-19 01:54:46.574: W/System.err(32377): java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
02-19 01:54:46.584: W/System.err(32377):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:545)
02-19 01:54:46.584: W/System.err(32377):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:509)
02-19 01:54:46.584: W/System.err(32377):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
02-19 01:54:46.584: W/System.err(32377):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
02-19 01:54:46.584: W/System.err(32377):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
02-19 01:54:46.584: W/System.err(32377):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
02-19 01:54:46.584: W/System.err(32377):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:134)
02-19 01:54:46.584: W/System.err(32377):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:161)
02-19 01:54:46.594: W/System.err(32377):    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:159)
02-19 01:54:46.594: W/System.err(32377):    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:233)
02-19 01:54:46.594: W/System.err(32377):    at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:145)
02-19 01:54:46.594: W/System.err(32377):    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:397)
02-19 01:54:46.594: W/System.err(32377):    at com.example.example.MainActivity$list3.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:776)
02-19 01:54:46.594: W/System.err(32377):    at com.example.example.MainActivity$list3.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
02-19 01:54:46.594: W/System.err(32377):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-19 01:54:46.604: W/System.err(32377):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-19 01:54:46.604: W/System.err(32377):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-19 01:54:46.604: W/System.err(32377):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-19 01:54:46.604: W/System.err(32377):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-19 01:54:46.604: W/System.err(32377):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-19 01:54:46.604: W/System.err(32377): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
02-19 01:54:46.614: W/System.err(32377):    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
02-19 01:54:46.614: W/System.err(32377):    at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:141)
02-19 01:54:46.614: W/System.err(32377):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
02-19 01:54:46.614: W/System.err(32377):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
```

Comment: You could also mention in the post that what is the problem, by saying it doesn't work perfectly is a bit wide comment.

Comment: @Niko Hi Niko .The progress dialog keeps displaying and then disappears with toast "Done" but it does not update any data in listview .BUt sometimes it updates.I dont know why?

Comment: I would need to see more code, how do you handle the adapter data updation?

Comment: @Niko hold on updating the rest of the code.

Comment: maybe your asynctask overwrite other asynctask results?

Comment: @marcin_j no it works perfectly on mobile network.

Comment: @Niko check it out now.

Comment: you dont need runOnUiThread in onPostExecute, it already runs on UI thread. Second, dont update arraylist1 in your doInBackground if it is actively used in ListViews adapter.

Comment: @marcin_j Can you please elaborate `dont update arraylist1 in your doInBackground if it is actively used in ListViews adapter.`

Comment: Are you getting some expections in case when it doesn't work?

Comment: @jason sorry, this is not important in your code case because you are not using those arraylists before asynctask execution. I would anyway try removing those runOnUiThread cals from onPostExecute.

Answer (score 0):

From the `LogCat` I see you are gettin connection timeout, so you should not be expecting any data in your lists. Instead you should be handling this error case to inform the user that there was an error.

Comment: sorry that was a typo.Its edited in q above.Is there anything else which I need to change.